# Cannot Connect Using SSH: UseDNS terminating

Tags: ssh

When I attempt to login via ssh like so `ssh marc_mtpt0@m3pt0.com` I get this response:

```
/etc/ssh_config: line 51: Bad configuration option: UseDNS 
/etc/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options lost connection
```

I've done this plenty in the past but it's no longer working properly. Not sure where to go from here or how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As the message says, `UseDNS` is not a valid option name in `/etc/ssh_config`. There is a server option called `UseDNS`; presumably you meant to put this line in `/etc/sshd_config` and edited the wrong file.

Comment: I actually have no idea how that line got into the ssh_config file at all because I've never edited these files before. Slightly confused at how it got in there. But it's all good now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Marc I recommend [putting /etc under version control](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25246/managing-multiple-configurations-etc-with-a-vcs). I use etckeeper wherever it's available.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out line 51 in the ssh_config file worked.